# Como preencher um DropdownListe com ASP MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, sql-server, aplicação-web

Boa tarde, como eu posso preencher um dropdown com dados de um banco de dados utilizando Ado.net puro (código) e sem utilizar Entity framework?

Eu tenho duas tabelas em meu banco que se relacionam. Primeiro devo cadastrar um departamento e ao cadastrar um usuário, haverá um dropdown que carregará os departamentos cadastrados.

No model do usuário Model do usuário eu defini o seguinte:

```
public List<SelectListItem> ListaDepartamento { get; set; }
    public int DepartamentoSelecionado { get; set; }
```

Criei um arquivo que chama usuarioHandler e criei uma função que consulta os departamentos

```
 public List<DepartamentoModel> DepList()
    {
        Conexao();

        List<DepartamentoModel> listaDepartamento = new List<DepartamentoModel>();

        string query = "select * from departamento";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query, con);

        SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();

        con.Open();
        adapter.Fill(dt);
        con.Close();

        foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
        {
            listaDepartamento.Add(new DepartamentoModel
            {
                Id = Convert.ToInt32(dr["id"]),
                Nome = Convert.ToString(dr["nome"])                   
            });
        }
        return listaDepartamento;
    }
```

No meu controller eu chamo dentro do metodo get Cadastrar, a listagem de departamentos

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult Cadastrar()
    {
        UsuarioHandler usuariohandler = new UsuarioHandler();
        ModelState.Clear();
        return View(usuariohandler.DepList());
    }
```

e minha view:

```
@model projetinho.Models.UsuarioModel

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>UsuarioModel</h4>        
    @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.ListaDepartamento, new SelectList(Model.ListaDepartamento, "Value", "Text"), "Selecione")       
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
       <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```

Ao executar obtive o seguinte erro:

```
O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[projeto.Models.DepartamentoModel]', mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo 'projeto.Models.UsuarioModel'.
```

Comment: Qual é o erro ou problema específico?

Comment: Minha dúvida maior é como preencher um dropdown. Eu segui um modelo de listagem que eu tenho, mas não funcionou. Ele exibe o erro:  O item de modelo inserido no dicionário é do tipo'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[projeto.Models.DepartamentoModel]', mas esse dicionário requer um item do tipo 'projeto.Models.UsuarioModel'.

Comment: Isso é porque você declara na sua view  `@model projetinho.Models.UsuarioModel` e envia uma `List<DepartamentoModel>` na sua `Controller` em return `View(usuariohandler.DepList());`

Comment: @LeandroAngelo bem observado! Muito obrigado pela ajuda.!!

Answer (score 1):

Os métodos de DropDown do MVC usam listas `SelectList` com os dados. Elas também suportam armazenar a última seleção do usuário, aliás. Então você pode ou enviar essa `SelectList` por ViewBag ou adicionar uma propriedade ao seu modelo.

```
public SelectList DepList(){
    Conexao();

    List<DepartamentoModel> listaDepartamento = new List<DepartamentoModel>();

    // resto do código aqui

    // Lista/coleção com os dados, valor de cada opção do dropdown,
    // texto de cada opção e opção selecionada da lista
    SelectList dropdownDepartamento = new SelectList(listaDepartamento, "id", "nome", null);

    return dropdownDepartamento;
}
```

Ou por ViewBag.

```
public ActionResult Cadastrar(){
    UsuarioHandler usuarioHandler = new UsuarioHandler();
    ModelState.Clear();
    ViewBag.departamentos = new SelectList(usuarioHandler.DepList(), "id", "nome", null);
}
```

Aí na View

```
@Html.DropdownListFor(model => model.ListaDepartamento, ViewBag.departamentos as SelectList, new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela sua ajuda, tiramonium!! Deu certo usando ViewBag

Comment: Tavlez fosse melhor você criar uma ViewModel com a estrutura necessária para a sua view

Comment: O dropdown está sendo preenchido com valores do banco de dados, entretanto eu estou tendo o seguinte erro quando eu mando salvar:

System.InvalidOperationException: 'Não existe item ViewData do tipo 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' que possui a chave 'ListaDepartamento'.'

Comment: É porque você precisa adicionar a declaração da ViewBag tanto no método `HttpGet` quanto no `HttpPost`, caso o post redirecione pra mesma View.